# How to chomp lines in conditional statements in tf templates?

Tags: terraform

I'm doing this in a template:

```
%{ if myvar != "sss" }
bunch
of
text
%{ else }
some 
other 
text
%{ endif }
```

This works but there is a new line where the if statement is. I could put the first line of the block of text on the same line but I don't consider this readable:

```
%{ if myvar != "sss" }bunch
of
text
%{ else }some
other 
text%{ endif }
```

In Go templates. I could do something like this to chomp the new lines:

```
%{- if myvar != "sss" }
bunch
of
text
%{- else }
some 
other 
text
%{- endif }
```

How do you do this in tf?

Comment: A quick reminder about using a spell-checker here - it will save volunteer editors a lot of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [strip markers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#whitespace-stripping) `~` to remove whitespace and newlines in directives:

```
%{ if myvar != "sss" ~}
bunch
of
text
%{ else ~}
some 
other 
text
%{ endif ~}
```

That will remove your undesired newlines in your rendered output String from your template (assuming return from e.g. `templatefile` function).

Answer (score 13):

actually `~` in the end might cause you missconfiguration, when you try to create yaml file for example

```
foo:
  aaa: aaa
  %{ if enabled ~}
  bar:
    baz: ${baz}
  %{ endif ~}
  bbb: bbb
```

gives you wron yaml like this:

```
> templatefile("sss.yaml", {enabled=true,baz="baz"})
foo:
  aaa: aaa
    bar:
    baz: baz
    bbb: bbb
```

---

this one will return correct yaml but with new lins

```
foo:
  aaa: aaa
  %{ if enabled }
  bar:
    baz: ${baz}
  %{ endif }
  bbb: bbb
```

```
> templatefile("sss.yaml", {enabled=true,baz="baz"})
foo:
  aaa: aaa
  
  bar:
    baz: baz
  
  bbb: bbb
```

---

so to get correct file you have to plase `~` befo and after your expression

```
foo:
  aaa: aaa
  %{~ if enabled ~}
  bar:
    baz: ${baz}
  %{~ endif ~}
  bbb: bbb
```

```
> templatefile("sss.yaml", {enabled=true,baz="baz"})
foo:
  aaa: aaa
  bar:
    baz: baz
  bbb: bbb
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out something (which fits with the examples above) that the stripping does *not* continue consuming whitespace *after* it has consumed one newline, and also that when it goes *backwards* from a `${~` it strips whitespace on the current line but then does *not* strip the preceding newline, whereas when it goes forwards from a `~}` it will strip any consecutive whitespace on the current line *including* a trailing newline. This may be obvious, but is worth noting (e.g. if you're trying to do something funky with JSON & getting optional commas onto the previous line)